# Check if sum is true

Tags: php, function

I'm creating a PHP library called EasyDevop. Now I want to create a function to check if a sum is true. How can I do this? Like it must check if the answer is right? My current code:

```
public function isright_answer($sum, $answer){
    if($answer = $sum) return true;
    else return false;
}
```

Comment: `return ($answer == $sum) ;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short Way. This work fine now.**

**Use this**

```
function isright_answer($sum, $answer){
        return $answer == $sum ? true : false;
    }

    var_dump(isright_answer(5, 5));
```

Comment: return booleanExp? true : false can be rewritten as return booleanExp.

Answer (score 2):

You've missed a `=`

```
if ( $answer == $sum ) //true do something
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if($answer = $sum) return true;
```

should be

```
if($answer == $sum) return true;
```